# @media CSS is not showing on mobile site

Tags: css, fullcalendar, media-queries

I am having an issue with adding a scrollbar to the fullcalendar.js.

The following is the media query that I am using:

```
@media(max-width:560px){
    .fc-scroller{
        overflow-x:hidden !important;
        overflow-y: scroll !important;
    }
}
```

And there has been no changes on fullcalendar.js file and not sure why it is not appearing.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You all

Answer (score 0):

Was a height applied to the '.fc-scroller' element? If a height wasn't specified, the content inside that container will just stack.

Scrollbars will only appear/work if the height of the content inside your container is larger.

Comment: Yes the content inside the container is larger and their is a scrollbar appearing on desktop and tablet version. However, in the mobile version, the scrollbar disappears and the full height of the calendar displays

Comment: yeah I dont see what else to do